# how to identify a car after performing canny edge in a still image opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new in OpenCV and I want to know how can I identify the cars in a canny edged image 
because I want to count the cars in the image based on their edges.

Here is the canny edged image

[image: canny edged cars]

And here is the original image

[image: original image]

Comment: You need to provide more details. Does it have to be done based on edges? Will you be given a single image to count the cars, or will it be a video stream of the same location where cars come and go?

Comment: yes only a single image will be used since i plan to count cars for example every 5 mins i will extract a frame from a video and the extracted frame will be my input as a single image and from there i plan to count the cars present in the extracted frame.

but i dont know the right approach how to do this and i read about edge detection so i tried it but im confused on how can i detect if its a car or not based on the canny edge output

Comment: So you do have a video stream from which you'll be extracting images. Is it ok to have access and process all the images in between for the purpose of constructing a *background model* of the parking lot? I ask because that might be out of your control, or there might be legal issues here.

Comment: for now i dont have any video streams at hand but i plan to shoot a video stream of a parking lot for the sake of testing this study. yes its ok to have access and process the images in between.

i just want to know how can i identify and count the cars in the still image i will be extracting from the video stream. sorry so much questions i am really new at openCV and im a bit confuse. hope you understand

Comment: The thing is I believe it would be **very** dificult to count cars given a single frame without any context avaiable (hence my insistence on the video stream), unless you hardcode a lot of heuristics which are exclusive to this application, this parking lot, this lighting conditions, these car sizes, etc, etc. I will post an answer covering the general problem, which should be fairly robust across all these possible conditions.

Comment: thanks sir i will gladly appreciate it :)

or can you teach me on how to create a system that can identify a free parking space so that i can still count how many cars are there from total parking space - vacant parking space = number of spaces occupied (number of cars) present. i saw something that has a green box if it is empty and the box will turn red if its occupied. can it be done here in opencv?

Comment: That's presisely what my answer covers. To identify a parking place you could look for its delimitations on the ground, i.e. parallel white lines, using the *background image*. Then it is straighforward to place a nice box around it which change colors depending on a car, i.e. *blob*, being identified on that spot.

Comment: Also having a video stream would allow for an optical flow analysis of when cars are coming and going, which also makes this a lot easier.

Comment: sir if its not too much can you please give me a snippet of the code for my study so that i can learn and base my future studies in that thanks :)

Comment: @AntonRoth sir when i will base the counting on the total space - vacant space = number of cars parked i plan it to be a video stream can you please help me how to do it if its easy or can you show me a code snippet on how to do it thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about C++ or opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem of identifying dynamic objects on a given scene for whichever purposes, such as counting, may be tackled by the use of [background subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractor).

The idea is to use one of the implementations of this technique that OpenCV provides, [BackgroundSubtractorMOG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog) for instance, to construct a background model for your scene, by providing every frame of a video stream for it to process. It will identify what features of the scene are most probably static, to construct a syntetic image of the most probable background, the parking lot without cars in your case. You would then subtract a given frame from this syntetic background and count the *blobs* which have a minimum size, i.e. are big enough to be vehicles.

The results are impresive and I particularly love this technique. On youtube you can check some examples, I suggest [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkgDONNJRwQ), which is very close to your particular case. [This one here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f0lajhdIhE) is also very interesting, because it displays the syntetic background image side by side with the current frame, so you can see how well it works. Pay close attention around [00:50](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4f0lajhdIhE#t=50) on this last video, you can see the car slowly *appearing* on the background image, because it stays on the same spot for too long.

Comment: how can i detect blobs by comparing the syntetic background with the new frames? can you show me an example if its okay thanks. and also can i count the cars based on the blobs detected?

Comment: I already did the BGS method now i dont know how can i count the cars that will be part of the background since I plan to count the cars that are parked. OR how can i count the objects that are adapting as part of the background?

Comment: @Newbie if you successfully created the background model, that is, let it process a couple of dozen images, you can have access to it by calling `getBackgroundImage()` on the background subtractor object. One way to get the blobs, would be to use [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) to convert the background and current frame to gray, then [`absdiff`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) to compute their difference

Comment: @Newbie you could then segment this *difference image* to get the areas which differ most, say more than 10/255, and count the *blobs*. For that you could find **external** contours and count the ones which have a significant area.

Comment: so i need to extract a frame from the stream then change the extracted frame to gray and compare it to the syntetic BG? but im confused on how can i use absdiff i read the opencv guide does src1 means the BG? and src2 means the extracted frame and dst is the difference image? also i dont know how can i determine the areas they differ the most. so sorry so many questions i really want to learn opencv but im confused with some operations when i just read it

Comment: @Newbie yes, that's exactly how you use absdiff. To get the areas which differ most, use [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) to set any pixel smaller than a given value to 0 and the others to 255. this way you'll get big white blobs out of the difference image.

Comment: @Newbie check [this](http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189) out

Comment: thats the one i used for background subtraction but my only problem is from that code how can i get the blobs i dont see any sample tutorials about using absdiff i already extracted the background and the frame i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't humans good at spotting things? You even recognize the cars in the canny edge image, even though there is not a single wheel visible.

Anyway, the main reason why you're using canny edge detection is because you have a datastream of 10-100 Megapixels per second. You need to quickly find the interesting bits in there. And as your image shows, it works fantastically for that.

Now, to count actual cars *in parking spaces*, I would suggest a fixed setup procedure that identifies the potential parking spots. You don't want to count passing cars anyway. This step can be semi-automated by checking for parallel sets of lines in the canny image.

Once you've got those parking spots identified, it may be a good idea to define a mask. Use this mask to zero out the non-parking spot pixels. (Doing this before canny edge detection speeds up that process too, but obviously adds a false edge around the mask so you'd have to reapply the mask.)

Now it's really just checking if there's anything sufficiently big in a parking spot. You probably don't care if a motorbike is counted as a car anyway. To do so, use the canny edges to separate the car pixels from the surrounding parking lot pixels, and count if they differ (in color/brightness/texture/...)

Comment: can you provide me some example because im new and im a bit confuse on how to do it thanks